# Changing the value of Pandas Dataframe Column on by checking condition of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Dataframe have 2 columns one contains it unit and other having it value.

```
     df4 = pd.DataFrame({'D': ['g', 'Kg', 'l', 'ml'],
                         'F': ['500', '1', '1', '1000']})
```

I am trying to convert Kg into g and l to ml. I tried this:

```
    for row in final_df.iterrows():
        if final_df['D']=='Kg': 
            final_df['F']=(final_df['F']*1000)
            final_df['D']='g'
        elif final_df['D']=='l':
            final_df['F']=(final_df['F']*1000)
            final_df['D']='ml'
```

Expected Output:

```
    D   F
    g   500
    g   1000
    ml  1000
    ml  1000




    ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Could you please post expected output in code tags too once.

Answer (score 1):

So a couple of issues with this code Dheeraj. I'll try to explain them one by one.

- The first thing that you are trying to set your numeric type values under column F as String objects by putting them inside inverted commas and trying to divide a string via an integer. So obviously it will give you an error.
- Secondly, you're trying to put a conditional statement on the whole column by using final_df['D']=='Kg'; while you are iterating over row by row. So if you are doing this via iterations, then you should refer to a certain row as well, like this - ***final_df['D'][row]=='Kg'***
- Another issue is with the iteration method. While your loop was iterating 4 times, but it was of no good to iterate over using iterrows(). I'll suggest to use the length and create the range of values and use this as an index(which you can see on my answer below).
- And the last issue is rather depending on what were you trying to do; so if you want to convert Kg and Litre to Gram and mL, then you should multiply and not divide.

Here's the code:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame({'D': ['g', 'Kg', 'l', 'ml'],'F': [500, 1, 1, 1000]})

for row in range(len(list(final_df.iterrows()))):
    if final_df['D'][row]=='Kg' or final_df['D'][row]=='l':
        final_df['F'][row]=final_df['F'][row]*1000

print(final_df)
```

Result:

```
    D     F
0   g   500
1  Kg  1000
2   l  1000
3  ml  1000
```

Comment: Thanks For Correcting Me I have Edited conversion Issue :)

Comment: There are more ways of doing the same thing. One can use .apply() and inside you can use lambda functions or a user-defined function and them change the values depending on a condition. I believe it can also be performed using .where() and few other ways. But that would be too much for such case.

But do check those out @dheerajkhanna

Comment: Sure I Will Go Through apply() and where :)

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
df4['F'].astype(int).where( ~((df4['D']=='Kg') | (df4['D']=='l')),  df4['F'].astype(int)*1000)
```

**Output**

```
0     500
1    1000
2    1000
3    1000
Name: F, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Viveks answer using `np.where`, you could also consider the [`df.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), which is a method specifically to update a column where a condition is true:

```
df4['F'] = pd.to_numeric(df4['F'])
df4['F'].mask(df4['D'].isin(['Kg', 'l']), df4['F'] * 1000, inplace=True)
#    D     F
#0   g   500
#1  Kg  1000
#2   l  1000
#3  ml  1000
```

Answer (score 0):

With combination of `to_numeric` + `isin` + `replace` functions:

```
In [215]: df = pd.DataFrame({'D': ['g', 'Kg', 'l', 'ml'], 'F': ['500', '1', '1', '1000']}) 

In [216]: df.F = pd.to_numeric(df.F)

In [217]: df.loc[df.D.isin(['Kg','l']), 'F'] *= 1000

In [218]: df.D.replace(to_replace={'Kg': 'g', 'l': 'ml'}, inplace=True)

In [219]: df
Out[219]: 
    D     F
0   g   500
1   g  1000
2  ml  1000
3  ml  1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
df['F'] = np.where(df['D'].isin(['Kg','l']), df['F'].astype(int) * 1000, df['F'])
df['D'] = np.where(df['D']=='Kg', 'g', df['D'])
df['D'] = np.where(df['D']=='l', 'ml', df['D'])
```

Output:

```
    D     F
0   g   500
1   g  1000
2  ml  1000
3  ml  1000
```